# Connecting an android app to a IBM DB2 database

Tags: java, android, db2

I'm trying to estabilish a connection to an IBM DB2 database located on the Internet through my Android Application.
I added the "db2jcc4.jar" to the Java Build Path,with the following code:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;
import java.sql.*;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    String url = "jdbc:db2://5.10.125.192:50000/SQLDB";
    String user = "user";
    String password = "password";



    Connection connection = null;
    try {
        Class.forName("com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver");
        connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url,user,password);
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Driver non caricato", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Errore con url e credenziali", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }


    if(connection!= null)
    {

        Toast.makeText(this, "Connessione riuscita!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();



    }










}
```

}

I also tried to write the same code in Java without using Android,and it runs perfectly,but when i try to run it on Android,it shows lots of errors.
There's the logcat:

```
 04-10 21:43:04.183: I/dalvikvm(16135): Failed resolving Lcom/ibm/db2/jcc/DB2SimpleDataSource; interface 2532 'Ljavax/naming/Referenceable;'
 04-10 21:43:04.183: W/dalvikvm(16135): Link of class 'Lcom/ibm/db2/jcc/DB2SimpleDataSource;' failed
 04-10 21:43:04.183: W/dalvikvm(16135): VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Lcom/ibm/db2/jcc/DB2SimpleDataSource;)
 04-10 21:43:04.183: I/dalvikvm(16135): Failed resolving Lcom/ibm/db2/jcc/DB2SimpleDataSource; interface 2532 'Ljavax/naming/Referenceable;'
 04-10 21:43:04.183: W/dalvikvm(16135): Link of class 'Lcom/ibm/db2/jcc/DB2SimpleDataSource;' failed
 04-10 21:43:04.183: I/dalvikvm(16135): Could not find method com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2SimpleDataSource.setClientRerouteServerList, referenced from method com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver.changeDB2PasswordAssertions
 04-10 21:43:04.183: W/dalvikvm(16135): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 10320: Lcom/ibm/db2/jcc/DB2SimpleDataSource;.setClientRerouteServerList (Lcom/ibm/db2/jcc/DB2ClientRerouteServerList;)V
 04-10 21:43:04.183: D/dalvikvm(16135): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0001
 04-10 21:43:04.193: I/dalvikvm(16135): Failed resolving Lcom/ibm/db2/jcc/DB2SimpleDataSource; interface 2532 'Ljavax/naming/Referenceable;'
 04-10 21:43:04.193: W/dalvikvm(16135): Link of class 'Lcom/ibm/db2/jcc/DB2SimpleDataSource;' failed
 04-10 21:43:04.193: W/dalvikvm(16135): VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Lcom/ibm/db2/jcc/DB2SimpleDataSource;)
 04-10 21:43:04.203: I/dalvikvm(16135): Failed resolving Lcom/ibm/db2/jcc/DB2SimpleDataSource; interface 2532 'Ljavax/naming/Referenceable;'
 04-10 21:43:04.203: W/dalvikvm(16135): Link of class 'Lcom/ibm/db2/jcc/DB2SimpleDataSource;' failed
 04-10 21:43:04.203: W/dalvikvm(16135): VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Lcom/ibm/db2/jcc/DB2SimpleDataSource;)
 04-10 21:43:04.203: I/dalvikvm(16135): Failed resolving Lcom/ibm/db2/jcc/DB2SimpleDataSource; interface 2532 'Ljavax/naming/Referenceable;'
 04-10 21:43:04.203: W/dalvikvm(16135): Link of class 'Lcom/ibm/db2/jcc/DB2SimpleDataSource;' failed
 04-10 21:43:04.203: I/dalvikvm(16135): Could not find method com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2SimpleDataSource.getConnection, referenced from method com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver.connect
 04-10 21:43:04.203: W/dalvikvm(16135): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 10311: Lcom/ibm/db2/jcc/DB2SimpleDataSource;.getConnection (Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/sql/Connection;
 04-10 21:43:04.203: D/dalvikvm(16135): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x038f
 04-10 21:43:04.213: I/dalvikvm(16135): Failed resolving Lcom/ibm/db2/jcc/DB2SimpleDataSource; interface 2532 'Ljavax/naming/Referenceable;'
 04-10 21:43:04.213: W/dalvikvm(16135): Link of class 'Lcom/ibm/db2/jcc/DB2SimpleDataSource;' failed
 04-10 21:43:04.213: W/dalvikvm(16135): VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Lcom/ibm/db2/jcc/DB2SimpleDataSource;)
 04-10 21:43:04.213: I/dalvikvm(16135): Failed resolving Lcom/ibm/db2/jcc/DB2SimpleDataSource; interface 2532 'Ljavax/naming/Referenceable;'
 04-10 21:43:04.213: W/dalvikvm(16135): Link of class 'Lcom/ibm/db2/jcc/DB2SimpleDataSource;' failed
 04-10 21:43:04.213: W/dalvikvm(16135): VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Lcom/ibm/db2/jcc/DB2SimpleDataSource;)
 04-10 21:43:04.213: I/dalvikvm(16135): Failed resolving Lcom/ibm/db2/jcc/DB2SimpleDataSource; interface 2532 'Ljavax/naming/Referenceable;'
 04-10 21:43:04.223: W/dalvikvm(16135): Link of class 'Lcom/ibm/db2/jcc/DB2SimpleDataSource;' failed
 04-10 21:43:04.223: W/dalvikvm(16135): VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Lcom/ibm/db2/jcc/DB2SimpleDataSource;)
 04-10 21:43:04.223: I/dalvikvm(16135): Failed resolving Lcom/ibm/db2/jcc/DB2SimpleDataSource; interface 2532 'Ljavax/naming/Referenceable;'
 04-10 21:43:04.223: W/dalvikvm(16135): Link of class 'Lcom/ibm/db2/jcc/DB2SimpleDataSource;' failed
 04-10 21:43:04.223: W/dalvikvm(16135): VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Lcom/ibm/db2/jcc/DB2SimpleDataSource;)
 04-10 21:43:04.233: I/dalvikvm(16135): Failed resolving Lcom/ibm/db2/jcc/DB2SimpleDataSource; interface 2532 'Ljavax/naming/Referenceable;'
 04-10 21:43:04.233: W/dalvikvm(16135): Link of class 'Lcom/ibm/db2/jcc/DB2SimpleDataSource;' failed
 04-10 21:43:04.233: W/dalvikvm(16135): VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Lcom/ibm/db2/jcc/DB2SimpleDataSource;)
 04-10 21:43:04.233: I/dalvikvm(16135): Failed resolving Lcom/ibm/db2/jcc/DB2SimpleDataSource; interface 2532 'Ljavax/naming/Referenceable;'
 04-10 21:43:04.233: W/dalvikvm(16135): Link of class 'Lcom/ibm/db2/jcc/DB2SimpleDataSource;' failed
 04-10 21:43:04.233: I/dalvikvm(16135): Could not find method com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2SimpleDataSource.getConnectionForChangingPassword, referenced from method com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver.connect
 04-10 21:43:04.233: W/dalvikvm(16135): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 10313: Lcom/ibm/db2/jcc/DB2SimpleDataSource;.getConnectionForChangingPassword (Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/sql/Connection;
04-10 21:43:04.233: D/dalvikvm(16135): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0483
04-10 21:43:04.243: I/dalvikvm(16135): Failed resolving Lcom/ibm/db2/jcc/DB2SimpleDataSource; interface 2532 'Ljavax/naming/Referenceable;'
04-10 21:43:04.243: W/dalvikvm(16135): Link of class 'Lcom/ibm/db2/jcc/DB2SimpleDataSource;' failed
04-10 21:43:04.243: E/dalvikvm(16135): Could not find class 'com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2SimpleDataSource', referenced from method com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver.getDataSource
04-10 21:43:04.243: W/dalvikvm(16135): VFY: unable to resolve check-cast 1235 (Lcom/ibm/db2/jcc/DB2SimpleDataSource;) in Lcom/ibm/db2/jcc/DB2Driver;
04-10 21:43:04.243: D/dalvikvm(16135): VFY: replacing opcode 0x1f at 0x00d6
04-10 21:43:04.253: I/dalvikvm(16135): Failed resolving Lcom/ibm/db2/jcc/DB2SimpleDataSource; interface 2532 'Ljavax/naming/Referenceable;'
04-10 21:43:04.253: W/dalvikvm(16135): Link of class 'Lcom/ibm/db2/jcc/DB2SimpleDataSource;' failed
04-10 21:43:04.253: D/dalvikvm(16135): DexOpt: unable to opt direct call 0x2842 at 0xdc in Lcom/ibm/db2/jcc/DB2Driver;.getDataSource
04-10 21:43:04.253: I/dalvikvm(16135): Failed resolving Lcom/ibm/db2/jcc/DB2SimpleDataSource; interface 2532 'Ljavax/naming/Referenceable;'
04-10 21:43:04.253: W/dalvikvm(16135): Link of class 'Lcom/ibm/db2/jcc/DB2SimpleDataSource;' failed
04-10 21:43:04.253: I/dalvikvm(16135): DexOpt: unable to optimize instance field ref 0x0dc2 at 0xe0 in Lcom/ibm/db2/jcc/DB2Driver;.getDataSource
04-10 21:43:04.373: W/dalvikvm(16135): VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Ljavax/transaction/xa/XAResource;)
04-10 21:43:04.373: W/dalvikvm(16135): VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Ljavax/transaction/xa/XAResource;)
04-10 21:43:04.373: E/dalvikvm(16135): Could not find class 'javax.transaction.xa.XAResource', referenced from method com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.ib.a
04-10 21:43:04.373: W/dalvikvm(16135): VFY: unable to resolve check-cast 2561 (Ljavax/transaction/xa/XAResource;) in Lcom/ibm/db2/jcc/am/ib;
04-10 21:43:04.373: D/dalvikvm(16135): VFY: replacing opcode 0x1f at 0x000c
04-10 21:43:04.383: W/dalvikvm(16135): VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Ljavax/transaction/xa/XAResource;)
04-10 21:43:04.383: E/dalvikvm(16135): Could not find class 'javax.transaction.xa.XAResource', referenced from method com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.ib.a
04-10 21:43:04.383: W/dalvikvm(16135): VFY: unable to resolve const-class 2561 (Ljavax/transaction/xa/XAResource;) in Lcom/ibm/db2/jcc/am/ib;
04-10 21:43:04.383: D/dalvikvm(16135): VFY: replacing opcode 0x1c at 0x003f
04-10 21:43:04.383: E/dalvikvm(16135): Could not find class 'javax.transaction.xa.XAResource', referenced from method com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.ib.a
04-10 21:43:04.383: W/dalvikvm(16135): VFY: unable to resolve const-class 2561 (Ljavax/transaction/xa/XAResource;) in Lcom/ibm/db2/jcc/am/ib;
04-10 21:43:04.383: D/dalvikvm(16135): VFY: replacing opcode 0x1c at 0x005c
04-10 21:43:04.393: E/dalvikvm(16135): Could not find class 'javax.management.MBeanServer', referenced from method com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.ib.h
04-10 21:43:04.393: W/dalvikvm(16135): VFY: unable to resolve check-cast 2521 (Ljavax/management/MBeanServer;) in Lcom/ibm/db2/jcc/am/ib;
04-10 21:43:04.393: D/dalvikvm(16135): VFY: replacing opcode 0x1f at 0x000d
04-10 21:43:04.443: D/dalvikvm(16135): DexOpt: unable to opt direct call 0x6664 at 0x19 in Lcom/ibm/db2/jcc/am/ib;.h
04-10 21:43:04.463: I/dalvikvm(16135): Failed resolving Lcom/ibm/db2/jcc/DB2ClientRerouteServerList; interface 2532 'Ljavax/naming/Referenceable;'
04-10 21:43:04.463: W/dalvikvm(16135): Link of class 'Lcom/ibm/db2/jcc/DB2ClientRerouteServerList;' failed
04-10 21:43:04.483: I/dalvikvm(16135): Failed resolving Lcom/ibm/db2/jcc/DB2ClientRerouteServerList; interface 2532 'Ljavax/naming/Referenceable;'
04-10 21:43:04.483: W/dalvikvm(16135): Link of class 'Lcom/ibm/db2/jcc/DB2ClientRerouteServerList;' failed
04-10 21:43:04.483: I/dalvikvm(16135): Failed resolving Lcom/ibm/db2/jcc/DB2ClientRerouteServerList; interface 2532 'Ljavax/naming/Referenceable;'
04-10 21:43:04.483: W/dalvikvm(16135): Link of class 'Lcom/ibm/db2/jcc/DB2ClientRerouteServerList;' failed
04-10 21:43:04.483: I/dalvikvm(16135): Failed resolving Lcom/ibm/db2/jcc/DB2ClientRerouteServerList; interface 2532 'Ljavax/naming/Referenceable;'
04-10 21:43:04.483: W/dalvikvm(16135): Link of class 'Lcom/ibm/db2/jcc/DB2ClientRerouteServerList;' failed
04-10 21:43:04.483: I/dalvikvm(16135): Could not find method com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2ClientRerouteServerList.getAlternateServerName, referenced from method com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2BaseDataSource.areServerListsSame
04-10 21:43:04.483: W/dalvikvm(16135): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 9808: Lcom/ibm/db2/jcc/DB2ClientRerouteServerList;.getAlternateServerName ()[Ljava/lang/String;
04-10 21:43:04.483: D/dalvikvm(16135): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0008
04-10 21:43:04.533: I/dalvikvm(16135): Failed resolving Lcom/ibm/db2/jcc/DB2ClientRerouteServerList; interface 2532 'Ljavax/naming/Referenceable;'
04-10 21:43:04.533: W/dalvikvm(16135): Link of class 'Lcom/ibm/db2/jcc/DB2ClientRerouteServerList;' failed
04-10 21:43:04.533: W/dalvikvm(16135): VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Ljavax/naming/Context;)
04-10 21:43:04.533: I/dalvikvm(16135): Failed resolving Lcom/ibm/db2/jcc/DB2ClientRerouteServerList; interface 2532 'Ljavax/naming/Referenceable;'
04-10 21:43:04.533: W/dalvikvm(16135): Link of class 'Lcom/ibm/db2/jcc/DB2ClientRerouteServerList;' failed
04-10 21:43:04.533: W/dalvikvm(16135): VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Lcom/ibm/db2/jcc/DB2ClientRerouteServerList;)
04-10 21:43:04.533: E/dalvikvm(16135): Could not find class 'javax.naming.Context', referenced from method com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2BaseDataSource.updateJNDIRegistry
04-10 21:43:04.533: W/dalvikvm(16135): VFY: unable to resolve check-cast 2526 (Ljavax/naming/Context;) in Lcom/ibm/db2/jcc/DB2BaseDataSource;
04-10 21:43:04.533: D/dalvikvm(16135): VFY: replacing opcode 0x1f at 0x002a
04-10 21:43:04.553: I/dalvikvm(16135): Failed resolving Lcom/ibm/db2/jcc/DB2ClientRerouteServerList; interface 2532 'Ljavax/naming/Referenceable;'
04-10 21:43:04.553: W/dalvikvm(16135): Link of class 'Lcom/ibm/db2/jcc/DB2ClientRerouteServerList;' failed
04-10 21:43:04.553: I/dalvikvm(16135): Failed resolving Lcom/ibm/db2/jcc/DB2ClientRerouteServerList; interface 2532 'Ljavax/naming/Referenceable;'
04-10 21:43:04.553: W/dalvikvm(16135): Link of class 'Lcom/ibm/db2/jcc/DB2ClientRerouteServerList;' failed
04-10 21:43:04.553: W/dalvikvm(16135): VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Lcom/ibm/db2/jcc/DB2ClientRerouteServerList;)
04-10 21:43:04.553: W/dalvikvm(16135): VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Ljavax/naming/Context;)
04-10 21:43:04.563: D/dalvikvm(16135): GC_CONCURRENT freed 260K, 14% free 9496K/10951K, paused 25ms+19ms, total 97ms
04-10 21:43:04.563: E/dalvikvm(16135): Could not find class 'javax.naming.Reference', referenced from method com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2BaseDataSource.getReference
04-10 21:43:04.563: W/dalvikvm(16135): VFY: unable to resolve new-instance 2531 (Ljavax/naming/Reference;) in Lcom/ibm/db2/jcc/DB2BaseDataSource;
04-10 21:43:04.563: D/dalvikvm(16135): VFY: replacing opcode 0x22 at 0x0001
04-10 21:43:04.563: W/dalvikvm(16135): VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Ljavax/naming/Reference;)
04-10 21:43:04.573: I/dalvikvm(16135): Could not find method javax.naming.Reference.get, referenced from method com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2BaseDataSource.hydrateFromReference
04-10 21:43:04.573: W/dalvikvm(16135): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 26221: Ljavax/naming/Reference;.get (Ljava/lang/String;)Ljavax/naming/RefAddr;
04-10 21:43:04.573: D/dalvikvm(16135): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x004d
04-10 21:43:04.573: I/dalvikvm(16135): Failed resolving Lcom/ibm/db2/jcc/DB2ClientRerouteServerList; interface 2532 'Ljavax/naming/Referenceable;'
04-10 21:43:04.573: W/dalvikvm(16135): Link of class 'Lcom/ibm/db2/jcc/DB2ClientRerouteServerList;' failed
04-10 21:43:04.573: W/dalvikvm(16135): VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Lcom/ibm/db2/jcc/DB2ClientRerouteServerList;)
04-10 21:43:04.573: I/dalvikvm(16135): Failed resolving Lcom/ibm/db2/jcc/DB2ClientRerouteServerList; interface 2532 'Ljavax/naming/Referenceable;'
04-10 21:43:04.573: W/dalvikvm(16135): Link of class 'Lcom/ibm/db2/jcc/DB2ClientRerouteServerList;' failed
04-10 21:43:04.573: W/dalvikvm(16135): VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Ljavax/naming/Context;)
04-10 21:43:04.583: I/dalvikvm(16135): Failed resolving Lcom/ibm/db2/jcc/DB2ClientRerouteServerList; interface 2532 'Ljavax/naming/Referenceable;'
04-10 21:43:04.583: W/dalvikvm(16135): Link of class 'Lcom/ibm/db2/jcc/DB2ClientRerouteServerList;' failed
04-10 21:43:04.583: I/dalvikvm(16135): Failed resolving Lcom/ibm/db2/jcc/DB2ClientRerouteServerList; interface 2532 'Ljavax/naming/Referenceable;'
04-10 21:43:04.583: W/dalvikvm(16135): Link of class 'Lcom/ibm/db2/jcc/DB2ClientRerouteServerList;' failed
04-10 21:43:04.583: I/dalvikvm(16135): Failed resolving Lcom/ibm/db2/jcc/DB2ClientRerouteServerList; interface 2532 'Ljavax/naming/Referenceable;'
04-10 21:43:04.583: W/dalvikvm(16135): Link of class 'Lcom/ibm/db2/jcc/DB2ClientRerouteServerList;' failed
04-10 21:43:04.583: E/dalvikvm(16135): Could not find class 'com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2ClientRerouteServerList', referenced from method com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2BaseDataSource.updateClientRerouteServerList
04-10 21:43:04.583: W/dalvikvm(16135): VFY: unable to resolve new-instance 1207 (Lcom/ibm/db2/jcc/DB2ClientRerouteServerList;) in Lcom/ibm/db2/jcc/DB2BaseDataSource;
04-10 21:43:04.583: D/dalvikvm(16135): VFY: replacing opcode 0x22 at 0x002b
04-10 21:43:04.583: I/dalvikvm(16135): Failed resolving Lcom/ibm/db2/jcc/DB2ClientRerouteServerList; interface 2532 'Ljavax/naming/Referenceable;'
04-10 21:43:04.583: W/dalvikvm(16135): Link of class 'Lcom/ibm/db2/jcc/DB2ClientRerouteServerList;' failed
04-10 21:43:04.583: I/dalvikvm(16135): Failed resolving Lcom/ibm/db2/jcc/DB2ClientRerouteServerList; interface 2532 'Ljavax/naming/Referenceable;'
04-10 21:43:04.583: W/dalvikvm(16135): Link of class 'Lcom/ibm/db2/jcc/DB2ClientRerouteServerList;' failed
04-10 21:43:04.583: I/dalvikvm(16135): Could not find method com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2ClientRerouteServerList.setPrimaryServerName, referenced from method com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2BaseDataSource.updateClientRerouteServerList
04-10 21:43:04.583: W/dalvikvm(16135): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 9816: Lcom/ibm/db2/jcc/DB2ClientRerouteServerList;.setPrimaryServerName (Ljava/lang/String;)V
04-10 21:43:04.583: D/dalvikvm(16135): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0036
04-10 21:43:04.583: I/dalvikvm(16135): Failed resolving Lcom/ibm/db2/jcc/DB2ClientRerouteServerList; interface 2532 'Ljavax/naming/Referenceable;'
04-10 21:43:04.583: W/dalvikvm(16135): Link of class 'Lcom/ibm/db2/jcc/DB2ClientRerouteServerList;' failed
04-10 21:43:04.583: I/dalvikvm(16135): Failed resolving Lcom/ibm/db2/jcc/DB2ClientRerouteServerList; interface 2532 'Ljavax/naming/Referenceable;'
04-10 21:43:04.583: W/dalvikvm(16135): Link of class 'Lcom/ibm/db2/jcc/DB2ClientRerouteServerList;' failed
04-10 21:43:04.583: I/dalvikvm(16135): Could not find method com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2ClientRerouteServerList.getPrimaryServerName, referenced from method com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2BaseDataSource.updateClientRerouteServerListOnConnection
04-10 21:43:04.583: W/dalvikvm(16135): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 9810: Lcom/ibm/db2/jcc/DB2ClientRerouteServerList;.getPrimaryServerName ()Ljava/lang/String;
04-10 21:43:04.583: D/dalvikvm(16135): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0003
04-10 21:43:04.593: D/dalvikvm(16135): DexOpt: unable to opt direct call 0x666b at 0x0d in Lcom/ibm/db2/jcc/DB2BaseDataSource;.getReference
04-10 21:43:04.593: D/dalvikvm(16135): DexOpt: unable to opt direct call 0x666f at 0x6d in Lcom/ibm/db2/jcc/DB2BaseDataSource;.getReference
04-10 21:43:04.593: D/dalvikvm(16135): DexOpt: unable to opt direct call 0x6668 at 0x7f in Lcom/ibm/db2/jcc/DB2BaseDataSource;.getReference
04-10 21:43:04.593: D/dalvikvm(16135): DexOpt: unable to opt direct call 0x6668 at 0x96 in Lcom/ibm/db2/jcc/DB2BaseDataSource;.getReference
04-10 21:43:04.593: D/dalvikvm(16135): DexOpt: unable to opt direct call 0x6668 at 0xa5 in Lcom/ibm/db2/jcc/DB2BaseDataSource;.getReference
04-10 21:43:04.593: I/dalvikvm(16135): Failed resolving Lcom/ibm/db2/jcc/DB2ClientRerouteServerList; interface 2532 'Ljavax/naming/Referenceable;'
04-10 21:43:04.593: W/dalvikvm(16135): Link of class 'Lcom/ibm/db2/jcc/DB2ClientRerouteServerList;' failed
04-10 21:43:04.593: D/dalvikvm(16135): DexOpt: unable to opt direct call 0x264e at 0x2d in Lcom/ibm/db2/jcc/DB2BaseDataSource;.updateClientRerouteServerList
04-10 21:43:04.623: E/dalvikvm(16135): Could not find class 'javax.naming.InitialContext', referenced from method com.ibm.db2.jcc.t2zos.T2zosConfiguration.j
04-10 21:43:04.623: W/dalvikvm(16135): VFY: unable to resolve new-instance 2527 (Ljavax/naming/InitialContext;) in Lcom/ibm/db2/jcc/t2zos/T2zosConfiguration;
04-10 21:43:04.623: D/dalvikvm(16135): VFY: replacing opcode 0x22 at 0x0011
04-10 21:43:04.623: W/dalvikvm(16135): VFY: unable to resolve exception class 2529 (Ljavax/naming/NamingException;)
04-10 21:43:04.633: W/dalvikvm(16135): VFY: unable to find exception handler at addr 0x2d
04-10 21:43:04.633: W/dalvikvm(16135): VFY:  rejected Lcom/ibm/db2/jcc/t2zos/T2zosConfiguration;.j ()V
04-10 21:43:04.633: W/dalvikvm(16135): VFY:  rejecting opcode 0x0d at 0x002d
04-10 21:43:04.633: W/dalvikvm(16135): VFY:  rejected Lcom/ibm/db2/jcc/t2zos/T2zosConfiguration;.j ()V
 04-10 21:43:04.633: W/dalvikvm(16135): Verifier rejected class Lcom/ibm/db2/jcc/t2zos/T2zosConfiguration;
04-10 21:43:04.633: W/dalvikvm(16135): Exception Ljava/lang/VerifyError; thrown while initializing Lcom/ibm/db2/jcc/DB2BaseDataSource;
04-10 21:43:04.633: W/dalvikvm(16135): Exception Ljava/lang/ExceptionInInitializerError; thrown while initializing Lcom/ibm/db2/jcc/am/ib;
04-10 21:43:04.633: D/AndroidRuntime(16135): Shutting down VM
04-10 21:43:04.633: W/dalvikvm(16135): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40d832a0)
04-10 21:43:04.633: E/AndroidRuntime(16135): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-10 21:43:04.633: E/AndroidRuntime(16135): java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
04-10 21:43:04.633: E/AndroidRuntime(16135):    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver.connect(DB2Driver.java:121)
04-10 21:43:04.633: E/AndroidRuntime(16135):    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver.connect(DB2Driver.java:115)
04-10 21:43:04.633: E/AndroidRuntime(16135):    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:175)
04-10 21:43:04.633: E/AndroidRuntime(16135):    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:209)
04-10 21:43:04.633: E/AndroidRuntime(16135):    at com.example.provaconnessionedb.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:25)
04-10 21:43:04.633: E/AndroidRuntime(16135):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5047)
04-10 21:43:04.633: E/AndroidRuntime(16135):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1094)
04-10 21:43:04.633: E/AndroidRuntime(16135):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2056)
04-10 21:43:04.633: E/AndroidRuntime(16135):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2117)
04-10 21:43:04.633: E/AndroidRuntime(16135):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:134)
04-10 21:43:04.633: E/AndroidRuntime(16135):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1218)
04-10 21:43:04.633: E/AndroidRuntime(16135):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-10 21:43:04.633: E/AndroidRuntime(16135):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
04-10 21:43:04.633: E/AndroidRuntime(16135):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4867)
04-10 21:43:04.633: E/AndroidRuntime(16135):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-10 21:43:04.633: E/AndroidRuntime(16135):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
04-10 21:43:04.633: E/AndroidRuntime(16135):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1007)
04-10 21:43:04.633: E/AndroidRuntime(16135):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:774)
04-10 21:43:04.633: E/AndroidRuntime(16135):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-10 21:43:04.633: E/AndroidRuntime(16135): Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
04-10 21:43:04.633: E/AndroidRuntime(16135):    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.ib.o(ib.java:931)
04-10 21:43:04.633: E/AndroidRuntime(16135):    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.ib.k(ib.java:840)
04-10 21:43:04.633: E/AndroidRuntime(16135):    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.ib.<clinit>(ib.java:658)
04-10 21:43:04.633: E/AndroidRuntime(16135):    ... 19 more
04-10 21:43:04.633: E/AndroidRuntime(16135): Caused by: java.lang.VerifyError: com/ibm/db2/jcc/t2zos/T2zosConfiguration
04-10 21:43:04.633: E/AndroidRuntime(16135):    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2BaseDataSource.<clinit>(DB2BaseDataSource.java:5579)
04-10 21:43:04.633: E/AndroidRuntime(16135):    ... 22 more
```

My question is:is there a way to connect an Android app to a DB2 database which doesn't involve using a web service,but just JDBC?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think you need to use the db2jcc.jar file.  The db2jcc4.jar file was compiled for JDK 1.6 and I don't think android supports JDK 1.6.